# Copy object data between clients using Photon Unity Networking

Tags: c#, networking, photon

I have a class that is structured as followed:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public int NumberOfPlayers { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPlayers { get; set; }

    public Game(string name, int num)
    {
            Name = name;
            NumberOfPlayers = num;
            CurrentPlayers = 0;
    }
```

I create a global variable when the game starts using

```
public static Game firstGame;
```

Using Photon Unity Networking, how can I share this single object's info between all clients I create?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a RPC that sends the 3 vars of the game class, and then on the receiving clients they create an object of Game based on the data sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an RPC call over other players, putting these values inside a dictionary object and then pass that object in RPC call. And on another side, you can unwrap this object.

E.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dataToShare = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dataToShare.Add("PlayerFirstName", PlayerInformation.loginDetails.FirstName);
dataToShare.Add("Avatar", PlayerInformation.loginDetails.Avatar);
photonView.RPC("InitializeMyPlayerRPC",PhotonTargets.OthersBuffered,new object[]{ dataToShare});

[PunRPC]

void InitializeMyPlayerRPC(object dataToShare)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = dataToShare as Dictionary<string, string>;          
    player.Name = data["PlayerFirstName"].ToString();
    player.Avatat = data["Avatar"].ToString();
}
```

I know you have already done, but if someone needs, it will help them.